# Как настроить приложение на Yii2 на хостинге?

Tags: php, yii2

Впервые устанавливаю приложение на хостинге на Yii2 (advanced-шаблон) и у меня возникла такая проблема, что главная страница сайта загружается и отображается, но при переходе по ссылкам я остаюсь на той же странице ХОТЯ в адресной строке появляются ссылки на которые я якобы перехожу. На локальной машине все работает хорошо. В приложении я изменил дефолтный шаблон и дефолтный роут на свой.

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
     'layout' => 'blog', // меняем шаблон сайта
    'language' => 'ru', // устанавливаем язык приложения
    'name' => 'мой сайт', // устанавливаем название приложения
    'defaultRoute' => 'blog/index', // устанавливаем начальную страницу сайта
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
                    
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'post/page/<page:\d+>' => 'post/index',
                'post/' => 'post/index',
                'zitie' => 'zitie/index',
            ],
        ],
        
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

    введите сюда код
```

Файл .htaccess у меня такой и находится в корне сайта.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

Вопрос, что я делаю не так? и то нужно сделать, чтобы я смог переходить по ссылкам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильной корневой папке сайта. Надо, чтобы корневая папка была frontend/web, а внутри лежал htaccess. Пришлось удалить домен и добавить заново. После чего все заработало.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```